# Format date into yyyy-mm-dd in text box where the only input is mm-dd JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

Trying to save some time on a HTML form that collects and stores data.

For my date fields I am currently using a datepicker but it is time consuming given the quantity of data that I am inputting.

I would like to replace the datepicker with JavaScript code that does this.

If I input  "5-25" into the textbox upon tabbing or entering the field would automatically format to "2017-05-25"

However, if the month is earlier then the current month (for example if it is currently May than Jan, Feb, Mar or Apr would be earlier) I would like it to return the current year plus 1. So if I typed 3-26 into the textbox I would like it to change to 2018-03-26.

Can someone help with the actual JavaScript code that could do this?

Comment: `onblur()` event will be helpful in this case

Comment: Seems like you have the basic algorithm here. Maybe try to write some code that implements it. There are a number of questions on SO about splitting strings that have dates in them. There are questions about formatting dates too. Put them together. Try that and if you have problems after that, come back with a more specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using yyyy-mm-dd for input is usually inconvenient for users, most prefer to type d-m-y except for some places where m-d-y might be preferred.

Using d-m-y also helps as it's easy to tell for partly written dates what the values are. E.g. 16/5 is 16 May in the current year, but if the format is y-m-d then I don't know if 5-m should be 2005 or not.

Anyway, sticking with yyyy-m-d, you can assume that if the first value is 4 digits then it's a year. If it's less, then it's a month followed by a day.

So:

```js
function setDate() {

  // Padding helper
  function z(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n
  }

  var today = new Date();
  var b = this.value.split(/\D/);
  var year = today.getFullYear();

  // If only a 2 part date was entered, create full date and
  // assume mm-dd. Otherwise do nothing
  if (b.length < 3) {
    year += b[0] <= today.getMonth()? 1 : 0;
    this.value = year + '-' + z(+b[0]) + '-' + z(+b[1])

  // For other values, make sure the separator is '-'.
  } else {
    this.value = b.map(z).join('-');
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('aDate');
  if (el) {
    el.addEventListener('blur', setDate, false);
  }
};
```

```html
Enter a Date:<input id="aDate" name="aDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd or mm-dd">
```

This doesn't do any validation, that can be added but should probably be a separate function. This one just formats the value, then it can be validated.

I added a bit of formatting so users can use any non-digit separator, e.g. 3/26, 3.26, 3-26 or 3 26, etc.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for taking the time to dominate life.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the question a shot, and developed a simple JQuery script that solves your problem:

```
$(function() {
    //Whenever you exit any input in your form
    $("form input").on("blur", function() {

        //Get the values on each side of the dash
        var $date = $(this).val().split("-");

        //If the date is given in a wrong format
        if ($date.length != 2) {
            //Perhaps some error-handling code here
            return;
        }

        var $today = new Date();
        $year = $today.getFullYear();

        //Trailing 0 formats
        $month = ("0" + $date[0]).slice(-2);
        $day = ("0" + $date[1]).slice(-2);

        //If today is later (geater) than the given date
        if ($today > new Date($year, $month-1, $day)) {
            //Set the date format to a year later yyyy-mm-dd
            $(this).val(($year+1) + "-" + $month + "-" + $day);
        } else {
            //Set the date to this year yyyy-mm-dd
            $(this).val($year + "-" + $month + "-" + $day);
        }
    });
});
//5-10 gives 2018-05-10
//5-11 gives 2017-05-11
//4-10 gives 2018-04-10
//6-10 gives 2017-06-10
//0x-xx gives 201x-0x-xx (trailing zero can be excluded)
```

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag or it mentioned in the OP. There is no reason at all to use it for this.

Comment: @RobG I presented a possible solution for the OP using the experience I have, whether or not he wishes to use it is up to him.

Comment: Answers are for everyone with a similar question, not just the OP. Anyone looking for a jQuery answer will likely search on jQuery tags, those who aren't, wont. It is not hard to convert your answer to POJS. ;-)